# Can gradle display compile errors only when running compileJava?

Tags: java, gradle

If I have some compile errors in my project and run `gradle compileJava` I cannot see the compile errors on the console. If I run `gradle --debug compileJava` I get a big stacktrace and somewhere in there is my compile error. Is is possible to just show the compile error if there is one?

Comment: Strange, it does show the compilation errors for me, without the debug switch. Maybe it depends on the type of error. Can you post both outputs ?

Comment: Which version of Gradle do you use?